# MySQL triggers to update field based on sum of column from another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables 'survey' and 'results'

```
survey table
-----------------------------------------------
survey_id  | name  | p1q1 | p1q2 | p1q5  
-----------------------------------------------
1          | John  | 10   | 10   | 5 
-----------------------------------------------
2          | Erick | 12   | 15   | 23 
-----------------------------------------------

results table

id  | Uptake | PY5Q1 |
----------------------------
1   | AZT    | NULL  |
----------------------------
2   | UPDP   | NULL  |
----------------------------
```

I'm new to triggers and am trying to figure out how to get sum of p1q5 in survey table and update it to PY5Q1 where id = 1 in results table
Any ideas will be appreciated

```
CREATE TRIGGER `results` AFTER INSERT ON `survey` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE results SET PY5Q1=(SELECT SUM(p1q5)) WHERE id=1;
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a trigger for that? You can use an update query. Also can you show some expected results?

Comment: Any ideas with triggers or query will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `results` AFTER INSERT ON `survey` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE results SET PY5Q1=(SELECT SUM(p1q5)FROM survey) WHERE id=1;
END
```