# SQL syntax error at line 2

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pmtct` AFTER INSERT ON `survey_data` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE pmtct_cascade SET PY5Q1=(SELECT SUM(p1q5)) WHERE id=1;
END
```

Trying to create a trigger to update PY5Q1 where id=1 in pmtct_cascade table with sum of column p1q5 from survey_data table
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pmtct`AFTER INSERT ON `survey_data` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE pmtct_cascade SET PY5Q1=(SELECT SUM(p1q5) FROM survey_data) WHERE id=1;
END
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of your code snippet so that OP can learn vs. just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different delimiter.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `pmtct` AFTER INSERT ON `survey_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE results 
   SET PY5Q1 = (SELECT SUM(p1q5) from survey) 
   WHERE id = 1;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the DB will terminate your statement at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.

And your subquery was incomplete also.

Comment: This is what am trying to to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579734/mysql-triggers-to-update-field-based-on-sum-of-column-from-another-table